# jQuery virtual id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there something in jQuery to uniquely identify a DOM node, if the HTML markup does not provide an id, i.e. `if $(NODE).attr("id")` returns `undefined`?

Goal: exclude a specific node of a specific class.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".accordion-right-content").hide();
    $(".article-image img").click(function() {
    $(".accordion-right-content").each(function(i,v) {
        // the following comparison does not work because of the missing ID
        if ($(v).attr("id") !== $(this).parent().parent().children(".accordion-right-content").attr("id")) {
            $(v).hide();
        } else {
            $(v).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Except the specific $(this).parent().parent().children(".accordion-right-content") to be hidden before shown again.

Comment: What is NODE? please show us the html you have

Comment: Can you please write the html or create a fiddle to help us understand your problem?

Comment: Each DOM node itself is unique. If you provide a more complete example and a better explanation, you will get more useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use not operator like this:

```
if (!$(NODE).attr("id")){
//do stuff here
}
```

And the following, you're having wrong:

```
if ($(v).attr("id") !== $(this).parent().parent().children(".accordion-right-content").attr("id")) {
```

Should be this:

```
if ($(this).attr("id") !== $(this).parent().parent().children(".accordion-right-content").attr("id")) {
```

Comment: You should be using `prop` instead of `attr`.

Comment: why prop? attr is okay.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr  There was a time when jQuery horribly, horribly muddled these two concepts.  They are different, so they should be treated differently.